# Embed Flash in IE not working

Tags: asp.net, flash-cs4

i created a small menu in flash that i want to embed into my website. The problem is it works in firefox but not in IE.

Could you help me please i am completely new to Flash

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" 
             codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" width="540" height="50">        
            <param name="main" value="/Flash/main.swf" />
            <param name="play" value="true"/>
            <param name="loop" value="true"/>
            <param name="scale" value="showall"/>
            <param name="wmode" value="window"/>
            <param name="menu" value="true"/>
            <param name="allowFullScreen" value="false"/>
            <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain"/>
            <param name="quality" value="high" />        
            <embed height="50" width="540" 
              align="middle" 
              type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
              salign="" 
              allowscriptaccess="sameDomain" 
              allowfullscreen="false" 
              menu="true" 
              name="main" 
              bgcolor="#ffffff" 
              devicefont="false" 
              wmode="window" 
              scale="showall" 
              loop="true" 
              play="true" 
              pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" quality="high" src="/Flash/main.swf"></embed>
        </object>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see what's wrong with your code.

Anyway I strongly suggest you use the [swfobject script](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to embed your flash objects. This will solve the issue that flash objects have to be clicked on in IE before they are played.